# forward or reversed biased?

Tags: diodes

[image: Assuming that the voltage sources are equal and greater than the barrier potential.]

Is it reverse or forward bias?

in real life and theoretical

for example: Voltages in the pic are 10V

What if I placed a resistor in series with the source on the right?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple: there is no answer. The circuit you've drawn can not be solved with the usual tools since it includes two different ideal voltage generators in parallel.
Let's say that the bottom node is \$0\text{V}\$, looking at the leftmost generator the top node should be at \$1\text{V}\$, but looking at the rightmost generator you can see there is a contradiction.

If you substitute the ideal generators with real ones, i.e. you put a series resistor on each of them, you'll get that the voltage across the diode is zero so that it is not forward biased nor reverse biased. If a generator is stronger, i.e. it has a lower series resistor, it decides the polarizations: the leftmost would reverse bias the diode while the rightmost would forward bias it.

Comment: And, as drawn, the infinite currents produced will make the state of the diode moot.

Answer (score 4):

In real life the two batteries are shorted out, and it doesn't matter what is across the diode.  If the batteries are well matched, then the voltage across the diode will actually be 0.

All around, this circuit is a bad idea.  All it will accomplish is to drain the batteries quickly.

Comment: And burn something...

Comment: thanks for the real life approach. sometimes I forget that people who ask question around here probably need an answer like yours more than one like mine. +1